# First Topology Manager GUI Extension

Tags: discussion

See the first [Topology Manager GUI extension](https://community.sdl.com/products-solutions/solutions/customer_experience_cloud/digital-experience/tridion/tridion-developer/m/mediagallery/1309), which lets you map Publication mappings for a Web 8 environment.

Quote:

> When you add a new Site Publication, the system provides default
>   configuration settings that you can use as the basis for your mappings
>   for that Publication. On the one hand, you can see publishing
>   environments that you can map to; on the other hand, you can see any
>   mappings that have already been added to the current Publication
>   previously, and that are not yet related to any environment.

This functionality is planned for a future version of SDL Tridion. Feel free to share feedback here on Tridion Stack Exchange Meta or in a comment for the extension.

Questions about this open source release are welcome on Tridion Stack Exchange.

Comment: As a follow-up, SDL Web 8.5 added an overview of a Topology Manager setup along with a list of configured capabilities. The previous Topology Manager GUI extension for Publication mappings is now _in_ the product. Be sure to remove this old mapping extension before upgrading to Web 8.5 or later (only if you installed it with SDL Web 8.1.1).